# How to compare two cells in two different columns in the same row while looping down column?

Tags: vba, excel, loops

Right now I have the code going from L2 and looping down to the last row in the column. If the cell value is less than the value of a cell from the "Previous" sheet then that cell is highlighted with the ColorIndex of 40. Works great.

What I really want to do though is to be able loop through a second column at the same time (they will both be on the same row at all times obviously). Logically it should go like this:

If the cell value (beginning at L2) is less than the value of a cell from the "Previous" sheet AND if the cell value at AE2 is equal to "#N/A" (note: at this point all formulas have been removed so the "#N/A" is a string) THEN highlight the L2 cell with the ColorIndex of 40. Any help is appreciated.

```
Sub Comparing()

Sheets("Output").Select

Dim UsedRng As Range, LastRow As Long
Dim x As Long

Set UsedRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
LastRow = UsedRng(UsedRng.Cells.Count).Row

      Range("L2").Select

      Do Until ActiveCell.Row = LastRow + 1
        If ActiveCell.Value < Range("Previous!L2") Then
            ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        End If

         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      Loop

End Sub
```

EDIT: Thanks for the replies. After tweaking things got the code to work as follows:

```
Sub Comparing()

Dim wsOut As Worksheet
Dim wsPrev As Worksheet
Dim r As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

Set wsOut = Worksheets("Output")
Set wsPrev = Worksheets("Previous")
LastRow = wsOut.UsedRange(wsOut.UsedRange.Cells.Count).Row

For r = 2 To LastRow
    If wsOut.Cells(r, "L").Value < wsPrev.Cells(2, "L").Value And _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(wsOut.Cells(r, "AE").Value) Then
              wsOut.Cells(r, "L").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You should [Avoid Select/Activate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for starters.  That will make it easier to just add another check for the second column.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I'll give it a read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After refactoring your code the change becomes easy (just a slight change to the `If` statement):

```
Sub Comparing()
    Dim wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim wsPrev As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Set wsOut = Worksheets("Output")
    Set wsPrev = Worksheets("Previous")
    LastRow = wsOut.UsedRange(wsOut.UsedRange.Cells.Count).Row
    For r = 2 To LastRow
        If wsOut.Cells(r, "L").Value < wsPrev.Cells(r, "L").Value And _
           wsOut.Cells(r, "AE").Value = "#N/A" Then
            wsOut.Cells(r, "L").Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

If `Previous!L2` is meant to refer specifically to row 2, and not to the row being processed, the reference to `r` should be changed to `2` in that spot.

Also, if the cell in column AE contains an error value of `#N/A` and not a string of `"#N/A"` (you can tell be trying to do `=LEN(AE2)` in Excel - if it returns `#N/A` then AE2 contains an error value, but if it returns `4` then AE2 contains a string value), you can test for that using `IsError`.

```
Sub Comparing()
    Dim wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim wsPrev As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Set wsOut = Worksheets("Output")
    Set wsPrev = Worksheets("Previous")
    LastRow = wsOut.UsedRange(wsOut.UsedRange.Cells.Count).Row
    For r = 2 To LastRow
        If wsOut.Cells(r, "L").Value < wsPrev.Cells(2, "L").Value And _
           IsError(wsOut.Cells(r, "AE")) Then
            wsOut.Cells(r, "L").Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried this out and (to a beginner) it seems to be valid but I get a "Runtime Error (13): Type Mismatch" when it hits the "For" loop. It's not clear to me what the mismatch is.

Comment: Think I should clarify:

`For r = 2 To LastRow `
            `If wsOut.Cells(r, "L").Value >= Range("Previous!L2").Value Then`
                `wsOut.Cells(r, "L").Interior.ColorIndex = 40`
            `End If`
    `Next ` 

The L in Output and the AE in Output are going down row by row. However, they are only matching against a specific value which in in Previous!L2.

When I modify it like above it works well, however when I add:

`And wsOut.Cells(r, "AE").Value = "#N/A"` 

it hits the same Runtime Error again.

Comment: @lookininward So you want the equivalent of Previous!L$2? If so, I will update the answer to change r in that spot.  Are you sure the value in column AE has been changed to a string value of `"#N/A"`, and isn't still an error value?

Comment: Yup, exactly. Using `< wsPrev.Cells(2, "L").Value1` works, however there is still the issue of the Runtime Error 13 when hitting `And wsOut.Cells(r, "AE").Value = "#N/A"`. I'm sure that the cells in Column AE are formatted correctly. I checked it manually and tested it using "General" and "Text" formatting and received the same error.

Comment: @lookininward  You can test whether cell AE2 contains an error value or text by doing `=LEN(AE2)` in Excel - if it returns #N/A then AE2 contains an error value, but if it returns 4 then AE2 contains a string value.  If it contains an error value, use the updated code I put in my answer about 30 minutes ago.

Comment: You're right, it does return an error... even though I formatted it as text. However, inside that same cell formatted as text if I type in something like "Hello" then the `=LEN(AE2)` returns 5, the length of the string. Is #N/A reserved?

Comment: @lookininward "#N/A" is not reserved, but I doubt whether you typed "#N/A" into the cell.  My guess is that you copied a cell containing a `#N/A` error code, and that means the new cell (even if you did a paste values) would still contain a `#N/A` error code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131423/discussion-between-lookininward-and-yowe3k).

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I was able to get it working with this added `Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(wsOut.Cells(r, "AE").Value)`

Answer (score 0):

if I correctly understand your goal you may want to try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Comparing()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim prevVal As Double

    prevVal = Worksheets("Previous").Range("L2")
    With Worksheets("Output1")
        For Each cell In .Range("AE2:AE" & .Cells(.Rows.count, "L").End(xlUp).row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlErrors).Offset(, -19)
            If cell.Value < prevVal Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @lookininward, did you try this?